# How to resolve a trouble in using Tabula?

Tags: arrays, pdf, import, extract, tabula

I'm a data analyst and first of all would like to thank you and your friends for a wonderful tool Tabula. I have been using it over the recent months periodically and during past week quite actively. And, suddenly the tool ran out of order. I even deleted it from my computer and downloaded again, however, could not resolve the problem.

One thing I hesitate caused a problem, is that I almost didn't delete previously imported files. Another cause may be the file names which were numerical. What do you think, could these be reasons for a trouble or not and how can I revive it?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards,
Karine.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.